# How to read contents from a file, do some processing, then write to a text box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

It's been nearly 20 years since I last used VB.NET and I've forgotten everything :( My project:

Read the contents of a text file and write to a text box
If the line contains a specified string, write to a second text box
Repeat until end of file

What I have so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.SourceText.LoadFile("e:\xdcc.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

    Dim Term As String = "Santa"
    For Each Line As String In IO.File.ReadLines("e:\xdcc.txt")
        If Line.Contains(Term) = True Then
            OutputText.Text = (Line) & vbNewLine
        End If
        Exit For

    Next
End Sub
```

Problem:
I can read the contents to the first text box and I can output a matching line to the second text box. It's not parsing the rest of the file and writing all the subsequent matches.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two mistakes here:

first, your `Exit For` statement is causing the `For` loop to end on the first iteration;

Second, as I understood in your question you want to show in the text box all of the matches found inside the file. You need to concatenate the 'Current text' with the next match.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.SourceText.LoadFile("e:\xdcc.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

    Dim Term As String = "Santa"
    For Each Line As String In IO.File.ReadLines("e:\xdcc.txt")
        If Line.Contains(Term) = True Then
            'OutputText.Text = (Line) & vbNewLine
            OutputText.Text &= (Line) & vbNewLine
        End If
    'Exit For
    Next

End Sub
```

That might solve your problem.

Comment: Yes exactly. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! If is the solution you are looking for, please, mark it as answer and I will be pleased to help you whenever you need!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Exit For`. that is causing the loop to end after the first round about

Comment: Thanks I just caught that as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. I removed that Exit For statement and in the If section I changed it to:

OutputText.Text = OutputText.Text & (Line) & vbNewLine

I now get the results that I was looking for